# Android Licensing Install Library but no .jar files

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have followed strictly the manual on developer.android.com.

I have dowloaded the LVL, import it on Eclipse,

then included the library project in my application with the "properties window".

After I get an error in my app

"The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/home/my_name/workspace/android_licensing/bin/android_licensing.jar' CreateYourCatalog       Build path  Build Path Problem"

Indeed there is no .jar file in my android_licensing" library; I tried to "build" the project but it did not include any jar file.

All your help will be greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I have deleted and downloaded again, the "play licensing library", then right click the
project named "android_licensing" choose "build project" and the android_licensing.jar appeared in the bin folder! After that it works!